# Is it possible in JPA to redefine inherited attributes as transient?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink, hibernate-mapping

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseBean{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    String name;
}

@Entity
public class A extends BaseBean{

}

@Entity
public class B extends BaseBean{

}
```

Is it possible to set the name attribute as transient just for the class B

Comment: yes , I used <transient name="name" /> in the orm.xml but it doesn't work and i tried the AttributeOverride and also it doesn't work

Comment: Annotate your property using _@Transient_  and make sure that it is imported from  _javax.persistence.transient_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't work. The `@MappedSuperclass` fields/properties are always considered and even when you use property-access and try to override the properties with different annotation, Hibernate will still use the one from the base class.